# How to create a text field input with mask in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text, android-compose-textfield

I need a text field in jetpack compose that works with a mask like this: `NNNNN-NNN` where N is an integer from 0 to 9. I need my composable function to have this mask in the `OutlinedTextField` :

```
@Composable
private fun EditTextField(
    labelText: String,
    value: String,
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp),
        label = { Text(text = labelText) },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType),
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChanged
    )
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hello friend, I just updated the question with a snippet of my code, `EditTextField` is a text field of mine, I need it to have this mask applied to the `OutlinedTextField` which is an internal function of compose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `visualTransformation` property:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { it ->
        text = it.filter { it.isDigit() }
    },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    visualTransformation = MaskTransformation()
)
```

with:

```
class MaskTransformation() : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return maskFilter(text)
    }
}


fun maskFilter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {

    // NNNNN-NNN
    val trimmed = if (text.text.length >= 8) text.text.substring(0..7) else text.text
    var out = ""
    for (i in trimmed.indices) {
        out += trimmed[i]
        if (i==4) out += "-"
    }

    val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 4) return offset
            if (offset <= 8) return offset +1
            return 9

        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <=5) return offset
            if (offset <=9) return offset -1
            return 8
        }
    }

    return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(out), numberOffsetTranslator)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!  What you've done seems to work fine, though it's relatively large code.  Do you know if it would have a more compact form using regex?

Answer (score 18):

Implementation of VisualTranformation that accepts any type of mask for Jetpack Compose TextField:

```
class MaskVisualTransformation(private val mask: String) : VisualTransformation {

    private val specialSymbolsIndices = mask.indices.filter { mask[it] != '#' }

    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        var out = ""
        var maskIndex = 0
        text.forEach { char ->
            while (specialSymbolsIndices.contains(maskIndex)) {
                out += mask[maskIndex]
                maskIndex++
            }
            out += char
            maskIndex++
        }
        return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(out), offsetTranslator())
    }

    private fun offsetTranslator() = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            val offsetValue = offset.absoluteValue
            if (offsetValue == 0) return 0
            var numberOfHashtags = 0
            val masked = mask.takeWhile {
                if (it == '#') numberOfHashtags++
                numberOfHashtags < offsetValue
            }
            return masked.length + 1
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            return mask.take(offset.absoluteValue).count { it == '#' }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextField() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { it ->
            if (it.length <= INPUT_LENGTH) {
                text = it.filter { it.isDigit() }
            }
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        visualTransformation = MaskVisualTransformation(MASK)
    )
}

object NumberDefaults {
    const val MASK = "#####-###"
    const val INPUT_LENGTH = 8 // Equals to "#####-###".count { it == '#' }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer everyone should be using. Way more flexible solution.

Comment: how to all digits and letters in specific order, for example "AA1111A"?